# Real time temperature monitoring and logging

Tags: windows-7, monitoring

I am running into issues with my desktop computer probably due to overheating. After running CPU and RAM intensive tasks for some time my computer crashes giving a blue screen. I think the culprit is overheating and in order to make sure I would like to install a software that monitors and logs temperature real time. Is there any software capable of this? I am not always sitting in front of the computer and I can miss the time the computer crashes, hence a software that logs temperature vs. time data at certain time intervals by saving the data on the disk will be of great benefit. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of temperature monitor and log utilities, but of course they all add to the overhead so the machine is likely to die a little sooner, also note that the final seconds are likely to go unrecorded, system crashes are like that.

[Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) may, *depending on the chipset that you are using,* be able to do what you need:

- Monitor CPU temperature & other stats
- Log them to a file
- It is free - Gratis & [Open Source](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor)
- Runs on 32-bit and 64-bit Microsoft Windows XP / Vista / 7 and any x86 based Linux operating systems.

[image: Windows Screenshot]

Comment: It has plotting capabilities, but I could not figure out how to have it record temperature vs. time data. Okay I found a csv file that has records in regular intervals and I will parse it.